# How to remove persistent ad notification

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, ads

I'm using an unrooted Android version 4.4.4 on an Alcatel One Touch Plus phone.

Sometimes when I'm online, I would get notifications of ads like the ones on the picture below. I can't seem to remove them by sliding them left or right. I'm also unable to find out what app is causing this by long holding the notification.

The only way I can remove it is by either clicking on it, or by restarting my phone.

How can I remove those ads and find out what app is causing them?

[image: notification ads]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>